# How to know if the solution for this angle ϕ is in units of radians or degrees?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I am studying out of interest a modelling approximation for a plectrum plucking a string (eg. guitar, piano, harpsichord) as given by these articles:

- http://recherche.ircam.fr/pub/dafx11/Papers/24_e.pdf (relevant part on page 3 of pdf)
- https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:wp454hs7976/Jack%20Perng%20Thesis-augmented.pdf (relevant part on page 75 of pdf)

The model works roughly like this:

[image]

The string is represented here as the yellow circle in cross-section. The red part on the left is the component the plectrum is attached to that moves (moving upwards along the y-axis here). The black bendy part is obviously the plectrum.

$F_p$ (the force from the plectrum) can be broken down in terms of $x$ and $y$ vector components as per:

[image]

[image]

Where E is the Young's Modulus, I is moment of inertia, and L' is how far along the length of the plectrum the string is contacting.

The only trouble I'm having in understanding this model is concerning the units of $\phi$. Is this angle solution going to be in radians or degrees? In C++, sin and cos take radians by default and you have to convert degrees to radians first if working from degrees. So I need to know which one I'm getting from this equation for $\phi$.

Is $\phi$ here in radians or degrees?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I haven't really read through, but the answer is usually radians unless someone has gone out of their way to use degrees (which often involves factors of $\pi/180$, etc).

Comment: If you are modeling a length, what are its units? The choice depends on the user. You can use feet or meters. Same with an angle. You can choose degrees or radians. The equations are the same not matter the units. For example, $E=mc^2$ no matter what units you use. You already know you need to use the appropriate units to work with $\sin$ and $\cos$ if you use a calculator or computer.

Comment: I don't understand Somos. The equation $ϕ = \frac{F*L^2}{2EI}$ - what units is that producing? F is force in Newtons, L is length in m, E is Young's Modulus in $N/m^2$, and I is Moment of Inertia without units I believe. So this equation produces a unit-less result for ϕ which is meant to represent the angle. I'm asking in this schema, if I plug SI numbers in for F, E, I, and L, what units will ϕ be in? Radians or degrees? I am guessing radians? But I don't know. Obviously I can convert it to whatever units I want after. But I need to know what that equation is providing.

Comment: Radians are a 'unitless' unit. For any angle, place a circle centered around the vertex of the angle. Then the angle (in radians) is the ratio between the length of the arc traced out by the angle (std unit: meters) and the radius of the circle (std unit: meters). One radian is the angle which traces out an arc length that is equal to the radius of the circle: a radian is a meter per meter (m/m) which cancels out. Degrees are also unitless, but there is an extra constant multiple of $180/\pi$. That is, one degree is the angle which traces out an arc length that is $\pi/180$ times the radius.

Comment: The standard measure of an angle is in radians. As described above, they fit perfectly into the metric system while degrees require a strange constant multiple (much like the conversion between a foot and a meter is awkward).

Comment: I briefly looked at the referenced papers and I guess that one needs to understand the respective equations in order to answer your question. Since these equations are rather special, maybe Physics SE is a better place to ask your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oddly enough, the angle should usually be given in radians. However, looking at the first referenced paper, I am 99% sure that they are using angles in degrees. The authors speak of ( after (6) )

> For small-angle approximations ($\phi<<1$), this reduces [...].

If this would be in radians, this would mean roughly 57° which is not really a "small-angle approximation".
Also, they say that

> when $\theta=90°$, there is no bending [...].

Which also indicates the use of angles in degrees. I would suggest contacting the authors. Usually, authors are very happy if someone is interested in their work and are willing to help. You could also try to replicate the given results since the authors seem to have provided all necessary data.

Comment: Saying $\phi \ll 1$ is the same as saying $\phi$ is $o(1)$... it just means $\phi$ is small.  And calling something a $90$-degree angle, rather than an angle of $\pi/2$, is idiomatic English... the former is much clearer to read, even when all the mathematical equations are expressed in radians.  In this case, there is no doubt that $\phi_0$ is in radians.

Comment: I agree that you would say 90 degrees instead of $pi/2$. But in a scientific paper, I have never seen that. I also agree that $phi$ *should* be in radians. In order to be sure, one must contact the authors.